# Using file_get_contents() on a domain with non-Latin characters

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Using PHP's fopen wrappers to obtain the source of a remote page, the following works fine:

```
$src = file_get_contents('http://www.somewhere.com/');
```

However, this does not, presumably because of the non-Latin character in the domain name:

```
$src = file_get_contents('http://www.sømewhere.no/');
```

Mind you the actual domain is a valid, working domain (i.e. *not* somewhere.com).  Is there any way to make this work using file_get_contents()?

Comment: An IP address don't matches exactly to a specific domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons for that.

And you can start examining from converting that name to [punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Btw, currently I cannot open that domain

Comment: Right...that's a sample domain. The real domain has the same ø in it causing it to fail, but it's not my domain so I didn't want to list it here.

Comment: I just tested this and it appears to work. Guess I'll spend the night learning more about how Punycode works so I can implement a fix properly.  Thanks!